# opus in a 32 bit linux program

Tags: linux, 32-bit, opus

I am adding opus to a program (that runs on CentOS servers) that is built using 32 bit libraries (i.e. "-m32" for the gcc compile and link, it is built this way for historical reasons). Can I use the libopus.a from a vanilla "./configure;make" or do I have to somehow force opus to be 32 bit also? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

A little research (i.e. running "./configure -help") showed me how to specify the "-m32" for the opus build: "./configure CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32" then "make" in the opus dir.

Some experimentation showed that this **replaced** the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS values rather than adding to them. So I found through a vanilla run what these values were and then added the "-m32" to them as follows:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-m32 -g -O2" LDFLAGS=-m32
```

This is not the best solution, there should be a way to add a flag to CFLAGS without having to specify all the flags in CFLAGS.